# ubuntu partitioner

Tags: software-recommendation, partitioning, filesystem, ntfs, ext4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is gparted a good tool for resizing an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1813/is-gparted-a-good-tool-for-resizing-an-ntfs-partition)

I have a backtrack 5 distribution which is based on ubuntu. During the instalation it somehow managed to create a separate partition ext4 on a external harddrive which was based on ntfs. Now this external harddrive is devided into two partitions. My problem is that I dont't think windows wil recognize ext4 but I also would like to merge those two back together. Is there any good partitioner for linux, which will merge both to ntfs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gparted](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gparted) is a partitioning tool available for Ubuntu.

GParted can [handle NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1813/is-gparted-a-good-tool-for-resizing-an-ntfs-partition).

Delete the ext4 partition and [expand](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted) the existing NTFS partition to fill the empty space.